# Mounting 19" PCs for in a mobile flight case

Tags: rackmount

I need to mount 4 3U 19" PCs in a mobile rack flight case. It is designed as a small demonstration render farm for events and visits at customer sites.

Standard 19" PC rackmount cabinets (fixed installation) have horizontal rails fixed on both sides of the cabinet for supporting the weight of the PC.

I have found many 19" flight cases for DJs, but they seem intended for light equipments, which are very shallow, and attached only on the front plate.

How could I attach these PCs which are deeper and heavier in that kind of flight case:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72nks.gif]

Comment: The PCs are 38cm deep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're going to find that kind of case in 12U or higher (you may want to integrate a network switch and/or a PDU as well, so I'd go with 14U), you could add rack profiles in the back - I would advise you to buy specific rack profiles, with the right quantity and shape of holes, so that you can use standard cage nuts or the rail's mounting pens. You can either rivet, weld or bolt them to the existing frame. Obviously bolting has some advantages afterwards, if you change your mind about the layout :) Most companies that sell complete racks can also sell you these profiles in steel or aluminum, in various lengths.

Next option is to order a built-to-order case from one of the many companies that make these cases. [This one](http://megacase.com/en/case/19-rack/) has a nice online configurator that will show you the different options (doors, locks, wheels, etc), but due to the bulk and weight it's probably wise to select a vendor that's reasonably close to you. Just google custom flightcase, there are plenty of them.

Yet another option would be to configure a rack kit to assemble **around** an existing open frame rack with the proper dimensions. An added benefit of this solution would be that it's the only one that will allow you to add shock absorption to your construction (using foam or specialized industrial shock absorbers). Many of these kits come pre-cut and pre-drilled, you just have to slide and rivet everything together. We assembled a fairly big (150*70*40 cm) case in less than an hour using such a kit (using a compressed air riveting gun - these cases are held together with literally hundreds of rivets) and glued cut foam in for shock absorption.

One last note: flight cases that can take a healthy dose of abuse are heavy, and you'll mount 4 PC inside, so the end result will be very heavy. Wheels may look a bit silly at first, but are a must, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the frame out and weld on some side rails!  Or build your own frame out of angle iron.  Or stick rubber feet to the PC's cases and let them sit on each other and on the floor of the DJ case.  You've just got to think outside the box! ;)

Another option is to ask your PC vendor.  It wouldn't surprise me if they've had a similar question before.